# boot shows failing processes after upgrading packages and rebooting

Tags: grub2, 13.10, freeze, reboot

I am really new to this, so if I did something wrong that is obvious to you, please just let me know because I have no idea what is happening. When I installed ubuntu 13.10, I went through all the set up like set a password and what not and everything seemed to work fine.

Once I finally got to the desktop and had everything working (or so I thought) there was an icon on the side that had popped up saying that there have been updates to programs or something. When I clicked on details I saw that things like firefox and a few other programs had updates, so my first reaction was to install them. After the install it requested that I reboot, and so I did.

The Grub boot menu popped up and I selected Ubuntu and it seemed to be loading up. However, a black screen showed with processes that kept failing, and eventually the screen would be stuck on either the terminal or the Ubuntu loading screen with the dots indefinitely.

This happened all 4 times that I installed Ubuntu from fresh. This time I have not updated any of the programs, hoping it works. Has anyone experienced this? And is there anything that I should do the make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: please edit your question to include the exact errors being shown. You might want to look for errors in the "System Log Viewer" app - find it via the dash.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought would probably be that either the ISO you burned wasn't good, or that a step is missing. I'll wait for someone else to step in and give you a more detailed answer, but I'll give you a tip or two.

Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can also type them separately (line before &&) and line after &&

When it asks for your password, you'll type it in but you won't see anything being typed.

**My final answer: reinstall the desktop.**

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```